# Recursive method to return substring enclosed in characters

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring, infinite-recursion

I can't use other methods or add parameters and can only call the method recursively. I can't really understand how to approach this problem. I am struggling a bit wrapping my mind around recursion so bare with me.

The substring will be enclosed between the characters first and last. Can someone please guide me? Aside from my base case I know what I have down is not right..I feel like I don't completely understand what is going on at each step.

```
public static String theSub(String str, char first, char last) {
    if (str.length() == 0 ) {
        return str;
    }
    else if (str.charAt(0)==first) {
        return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
  //infinite recursion..
    return theSub(str,first,last);
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, but I'll hint that each step in a recursive process has to approach the base case, so passing the same parameter values to the recursive call as you were called with is, as you say, going to give you infinite recursion.

Comment: It would help if you were to improve the description of what the problem actually is -- that is the problem your code is intended to solve.  It might help to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), with pages that are linked to.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide one or more examples of input parameters and expected output.  Should `theSub("hello[there]world", '[', ']')` return "there"?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The substring will be enclosed between the characters first and last. Can someone please guide me? Aside from my base case I know what I have down is not right..I feel like I don't completely understand what is going on at each step. ..."*

For example, if the string is *"f(f(f(x)))"*, and you want to get *x*.

Essentially, while both *first* and *last* are present, get the *substring* and make a recursive call.

```java
public static String theSub(String str, char first, char last) {
    if (str.length() == 0 ) return str;
    int i = str.indexOf(first), j = str.lastIndexOf(last);
    if (i == -1 || j == -1) return str;
    return theSub(str.substring(i + 1, j), first, last);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk you through the steps to create a recursive method that extracts the substring enclosed between the characters first and last.

```
public static String theSub(String str, char first, char last) {
    // Base case 1: If the input string is empty, return an empty string.
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    // Base case 2: If the first character of the string is 'last', return an empty string.
    if (str.charAt(0) == last) {
        return "";
    }

    // Base case 3: If the first character of the string is 'first', call the helper function.
    if (str.charAt(0) == first) {
        return extractSubstring(str.substring(1), first, last);
    }

    // Recursive case: Keep looking for the 'first' character.
    return theSub(str.substring(1), first, last);
}

// Helper function to extract the substring between 'first' and 'last' characters.
private static String extractSubstring(String str, char first, char last) {
    // Base case: If the string is empty, return an empty string.
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    // If the current character is 'last', we've reached the end of the substring.
    if (str.charAt(0) == last) {
        return "";
    }

    // Recursively build the substring.
    return str.charAt(0) + extractSubstring(str.substring(1), first, last);
}
```

This should allow you to correctly extract the substring enclosed between first and last characters using recursion.